# How to give tooltip messages for json key and values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a json like below, I am getting it from database and displaying it on my html view  page(using `ng-repeat` and displaying like form input fields, like if `key1` is fieldname then `10` is it's corresponding value which we enter in text box). Here I need, if I put my cursor/mouse over `key1` field then it should show some tooltip message(like: `it's a key1 field`), and similarly for all fields. Please let me know that how can I do this ? Is there any examples are available ? Thanks  in advance.

```
test = {
    "tests": {
        "testjson": {
            "key1": 10,
            "key2": "second",
            "key3": 20

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: angular directives for bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. There are also ones for foundation. If you're not working with a FE framework you'll have to build your own!

Comment: here's a tooltip I created https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/9wzaoa6e/14/ with pure html/css

Comment: @Rob, It can be anything whether Bootstrap, or any ? I just need to show any tooltip messages for each key/value(those messages are differ from each other) if I put my mouse/cursor on each key.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, thanks for your reply, but I need similar thing for my json keys/values, how can I do ?(those tooltip messages are differ for each key/value).

Comment: @Dhana something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/9wzaoa6e/15/

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will give you an idea about how to proceed further on your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.test = {
    "tests": {
        "testjson": {
            "key1": 10,
            "key2": "second",
            "key3": 20

        }
    }
  };
    
  $scope.getTooltip = function(key) {
    return "It's a " + key + " field";
  };

});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in test['tests']['testjson']">
      <label>{{k}}</label>
      <input  type="text" value="{{v}}" title={{getTooltip(k)}}><br/>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have one query here, for example if I need tooltip message something different for key2 and some other message for key3, then how can I implement like this ? The solution above is for only the similar messages only(any different different test messages), but I need something different  different messages for each key, Please let me know how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: modify the *$scope.getTooltip* function based on your need. **Tip:** you can use *switch* function do this stuff.